# Перенос компонентов между сайтами

Tags: php, cms, веб-программирование, компоненты, фильтры

Задача: из битрикса взять компонент (например, умный фильтр), на его основе сделать универсальный скрипт умного фильтра, который можно встраивать в любой сайт с любой CMS. 
Вопрос: возможно ли сделать это с компонентом или проще будет сделать свой велосипед?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Проще сделать свой велосипед", потому что у каждой CMS свои определенные поля и переменные для обращения, например, в БД, для поиска по сайту, все они отличаются по структуре. 
Как вариант - можно сделать выборкой по проверке CMS какой модуль запускать, но в с тем количеством CMS, которые сейчас есть - проще под каждый делать отдельный, поскольку "объединенная" компонента будет весит много и совершать долгую обработку всех исключений.